# Scope of Traits

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala and Akka and I came across an example that confused me. The following code sample was in 1 file.

```
class RestApi(system: ActorSystem, timeout: Timeout) extends RestRoutes {
  implicit val requestTimeout = timeout
  implicit def executionContext = system.dispatcher

  def createBoxOffice = system.actorOf(BoxOffice.props, BoxOffice.name)
}

trait BoxOfficeApi {
  import BoxOffice._

  def createBoxOffice(): ActorRef

  implicit def executionContext: ExecutionContext
  implicit def requestTimeout: Timeout

  lazy val boxOffice = createBoxOffice()

  // Uninteresting methods here
}
```

The part that confuses me is the `createBoxOffice()` call in the `BoxOfficeAPI` trait. It clearly states that the `BoxOfficeAPI` has a function which will return an `ActorRef`. However the implementation for that function is located in the `RestApi` class which doesn't have any reference to the trait.

How is it possible that the trait can access this method? What is the scope of a trait?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is it possible that the trait can access this method?

I think you're missing the fact that the trait itself has an abstract method called `createBoxOffice`:

```
def createBoxOffice(): ActorRef
```

Which is why it has such a method in scope. It has nothing to do with the declaration of `RestApi`. Whoever mixes in this trait will have to implement that said method. That means, for example, that if the `RestApi` class decides to mix in `BoxOfficeApi`, it already has an implementation available which it will use. For example:

```
class Baz extends Foo {
  override def quuux(): Unit = println("quuux")
}

trait Foo {
  def quuux(): Unit 
}
```

Comment: You are completely right. I also left out another trait named `RestRoutes` out of the code sample. This trait coupled the `BoxOfficeApi` to the `RestApi` which is how it reaches the implementation of the method defined in there.
Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: You example did spark another question though. You are using the `override` keyword to define that the function `quuux()` is getting overridden from the `Foo` trait. This isn't used in the example I posted. Is this an optional keyword?

Comment: @RemcoW If you're mixing in a single trait like this, you can omit the `override` keyword, but it is good practice to use `override` even though it's possible. There are use cases where it's mandatory.